# Confusion with Thu Johns Twitter Laravel 4 PHP package

Tags: php, twitter, laravel, laravel-4

I am trying to use thu john's twitter-laravel package. I am trying to dynamically set the access tokens and then get the user's home timeline. It says that the method doesn't exist. But I know for sure the method exists in the Twitter class. It is giving me this error.

Error:

> Call to undefined method
>   Thujohn\Twitter\TwitterFacade::getHomeTimeline()

My code:

```
$config = array(
    'ACCESS_TOKEN' => 'xxx',
    'ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET' => 'xxxx'
);
$tw = new Twitter($config);

return $tw->getHomeTimeline(array('count' => 20, 'format' => 'json'));
```

Comment: Why is the `TwitterFacade` class mentioned in the error message? Looking at the [source code](https://github.com/thujohn/twitter-l4/tree/master/src/Thujohn/Twitter) it is not used in the `Twitter` class. Are you sure the error message comes from the code you are showing us?

Comment: That piece of code isn't where the error is from, The error is from you calling the method from the facade. TwitterFacade::getHomeTimeline() would be the call. new Twitter is instantiating something entirely different.

Comment: @CodyCovey, so I shouldn't instantiate "$tw = new Twitter($config)"?

Comment: @CodyCovey, if i write "$tw = new TwitterFacade($config);" then it says "Class 'TwitterFacade' not found". I am sorry but I am very new at this.

Comment: @SverriM.Olsen, please help me, I am stuck for days and I am really desperate. Any help will do. If you have any other solution other then that libary then I am up for it. I used Abraham William's library. But now in laravel 4, there is a lot of conflicts.

Comment: @eddard.stark Okay, is that the entire code? [Try this](http://pastebin.com/YUFrXpHL). Also, if you get an error then show the *entire* error message (including file name and line number).

Comment: @SverriM.Olsen, I am trying it right now.

Comment: @SverriM.Olsen, it is giving me this error. {"errors":[{"message":"Your credentials do not allow access to this resource","code":220}]}

Comment: @eddard.stark You have to put in your actual credentials where it says `xxx` and `xxxx`. If you have done that then it means that your credentials are invalid, in which case you need to go over to [dev.twitter.com](https://dev.twitter.com/) and get some credentials.

Comment: @SverriM.Olsen, I have put my actual credentials. Let me try it again. Just a simple question. These tokens change for each user who has logged in, right?

Comment: @SverriM.Olsen here are my credentials. You can try it for yourself. But it is not working for me :(